# Database Application [Ideas]

Tags: libreoffice, database

I want to build a simple application that connects to a database (the database should be a single file and should not require a database server), adds data via a simple formula and has the possibility to print a requested part of the database in a predefined format.

What I need are some ideas how to realize this. My first attempt is using Libreoffice Base but I want some other alternative options before I focus on one.

Comment: You can use a MS Excel document as database and access it with a MS Word form (e.g. for serial letters). I think this must be possible with LibreOffice Calc and Writer too. But it seems to be a bit off-topic for an Ubuntu forum!?

Comment: @guntbert Forum, Q&A page, who cares. That is nitpicking!

Comment: ehm this sounds like a text file is more than enough? Just use the script to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest database available is [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which comes installed (or can be installed) with any Linux flavour possible, takes virtually no memory,, as little disk space as possible (and if you take care about the number of rows and the amount of tables, as little CPU as well)

If anyone comes up with *anything* simpler then that in the next week, I'll send them a bottle of real French Champagne!

Comment: Good One. +1...